# How to handle log out #appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have created a page that will log the user in but if the user is opening the App for the first time, how do I handle this and direct him to the login page.
I wanted to use

```
if (logIn == false) {//redirect};
```

It doesn't work for Titanium SDK studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Titanium.App.Properties for this. example

```
if(Titanium.App.Properties.getBool("isFirstLogin",false)){
  //User Logged in first time
}
```

and whenever user logged in set  **isFirstLogin** to true.

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setBool("isFirstLogin",true);
```

If you want to log the user out again in the future, you can remove the property

```
Titanium.App.Properties.removeProperty("isFirstLogin");
```